# QMetaObject::indexOfMethod() fails looking for slot

Tags: c++, qt

This code fails on second Q_ASSERT.

```
class A : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    void function(QObject *receiveOb, const char *slot)
    {
        Q_ASSERT((bool)connect(this, SIGNAL(mySignal(int)), receiveOb, SLOT(mySlot(int))));
        Q_ASSERT(receiveOb->metaObject()->indexOfMethod(slot) != -1);
    }
signals:
    void mySignal(int param);
};

class MainClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
    A a;

public slots:
    void mySlot(int param)
    {
        param++;
    }

public:
    MainClass(QObject *papi = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(papi)
    {   }
    void doIt()
    {
        a.function(this, SLOT(mySlot(int)));
    }
};
```

As I can see, if connect is able to lookup the slot method, I could do the same.

What am I doing wrong?
What other checks can I do to find out my mistake?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: typo: change `a.function(this, SLOT(mySlot(int)));` to `a.function(this, "mySlot(int)");`

Comment: From what I recall the string passed to `indexOfMethod` should be the "plaintext" string such as `"mySlot(int)"` rather than the embellished string produced by `SLOT(mySlot(int))`.  So try `receiveOb->metaObject()->indexOfMethod("mySlot(int)")`.

Comment: It may be useful to use [`QMetaObject::normalizedSignature`][http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#normalizedSignature] before passing the slot to `indexOfMethod`. Note that `connect` uses this method when the slot is not recognised.

Comment: You're right. I figuret out the problem time ago, but as question is "on hold"...

Comment: All of you are right. The problem is that SLOT() macro puts a number, before the function name, (0, 1 or 2, up to function type: method, slot or signal) but indexOfMethod needs normalizedSignature.
2 hours trying to figure it out... damn xD

Thanks to all.  

I like to use SLOT() macro because: using it, seems more Qt-like code, IDE helps autocompleting class name and IDE highlighting looks better. Yeah, all cosmetic reasons, I know XD